# How to handle UTF-8 emoji in sed on Cygwin?

Tags: sed, unicode, utf-8, cygwin, emoji

I've seen many topics about escaping and replacing a special character in SED, but none of them helped me.

I have this sed command I need to use on a file:

```
sed -i "s/This[^\|]\+/& (cool) /g" "file.txt"
```

For a reason I don't understand, it applies to this test case:

```
This is my funny  char and this | char is the char after which  i want to stop my job.
```

... and transforms it to :

```
This is my funny (cool) ڠchar and this | char is the char after which  i want to stop my job.
```

... instead of :

```
This is my funny  char and this  (cool) | char is the char after which  i want to stop my job.
```

Can anybody tell me how to handle this kind of case ?

Note : the file is UTF-8 encoded, I use Cygwin that is UTF-8 encoded and my SED command is in a ".sh" file that is UTF-8 encoded too.

Comment: The buggy character is this one : https://unicodelookup.com/#/1

The hex value of this character is : f0 9f 8e ba

Comment: The character is not special in any way. Make sure your locale is a UTF-8 one.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with GNU sed 4.5. I copy-pasted your sed command and input into my terminal and got your expected output: `content="&lt;div class=&quot;wysiwyg added-oneshot&quot;&gt;this is a &quot;&gt;&lt; test&lt;/div&gt;"`.

Comment: Thak you @Socowi, i tried with GNU sed 4.4 on Cygwin. I will try on another system.

Comment: Did you also set your locale to UTF8? You don't mention this in your post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the bug was due to the fact that I used SED on CYGWIN, as it worked well on GNU Linux.

Thank you for your attention.
I hope this thread could help another Cygwin user.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this issue on Cygwin (v3.3.4) with `sed` (v4.8). Although I'm not quite sure what happened here, I found that by setting a UTF-16 compatible **system locale** makes it works:

```sh
$ python3 -c "print('This is my funny {} char and this | char is the char after which i want to stop my job.'.format(chr(0x1f3ba)))" | \
  sed 's/This[^|]*/&(cool) /g'
This is my funny (cool)  char and this | char is the char after which i want to stop my job.

$  python3 -c "print('This is my funny {} char and this | char is the char after which i want to stop my job.'.format(chr(0x1f3ba)))" | \
  LANG=C.UTF16 sed 's/This[^|]*/&(cool) /g'
This is my funny  char and this (cool) | char is the char after which i want to stop my job.
```

By the way, always prefer single quotes when using `sed` in case `$` and `\` be expanded.

Comment: If a UTF16 locale works, but an UTF8 locale doesn't, I would guess that the file is UTF16 encoded and not UTF8. Did you verify this?

Comment: @user1934428 But my input is from python, not a file. By writing the message to a file, I can verify it's a `Unicode text, UTF-8 text`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck in a similar situation but no file is involved so it's not file encoding.

```
< 7:36a> <10%> C:\>echo gOlIaTh |:u8 sed -e 's/goliath/GOLIATH/gi'
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

< 7:37a> <15%> C:\>echo gOlIaTh |:u8 sed -e 's/goliath/GOLIATH/gi'
GOLIATH
```